# How do I extend the table plugin?

Tags: 7, views

I want to extend the basic *views_view_table* and add optional classes from a plugin form. I'm creating a new plugin. I'd prefer not to duplicate the views-view-table.tpl.php file nor `template_preprocess_views_view_table()`.

I've started like this.

```
'views_my_table' => array(
    'title' => t('My Table'),
    'help' => t('My table options.'),
    'path' => $path . '/plugins',
    'parent' => 'default',
    'handler' => 'ViewsMyTablePluginStyle',
    'uses row plugin' => FALSE,
    'uses options' => TRUE,
    'uses grouping' => TRUE,
    'type' => 'normal',
    'theme' => 'views_view_table',

  ),
```

Then, I extended the table class.

```
class ViewsMyTablePluginStyle extends views_plugin_style_table {

/**
 * Set default options.
 */
function option_definition() {
  $options = parent::option_definition();
  $options['table_options'] = array('default' => '');
  return $options;
}

/**
 * Provide a form for setting options.
 */
function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
  parent::options_form($form, $form_state);

    $form['hover'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Hover styling'),
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#default_value' => $this->options['table_options'],
    '#description' => t('Adds the hover class to table to enable hover styling.'),
  );

}
```

This gives me a blank table rendered from the template, but the preprocess function either it isn't firing or it isn't getting the right data.

Maybe I need to implement the table plugin with more options, then tack on the classes based on those settings.

How do I correctly extend the table plugin?